# PHP - URL gets malformed during redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

So, I have an image link that has this `href`:

```
http://www.app.com/link?target=www.target.com&param1=abc&param2=xyz
```

This is processed like so (I use laravel):

```
function out (Request $request) {

    $url = $request->target;

    $qs = $request->except('target');
    if ( !empty($qs) ) {
        $url .= strpos($url, '?') !== false ? '&' : '?';
        $url .= http_build_query($qs);
    }

    return redirect($url);
}
```

Most of the time, this works. However, lately, we've been experiencing an issue where `param1` and `param2` are attached to the URL in a seemingly infinite loop causing us to hit a `414 Request URI too long` Error.

The problem is that it happens so randomly that I really don't know where to check because I added a checker before the `return` statement.

```
if ( substr_count($url, 'param1') > 1 ) {
    $file = storage_path() . '/logs/logger.log';
    $log = "[ " . date("d-m-Y H:i:sa") . " ] [ {$request->ip()} ] - {$url} \n";
    file_put_contents($file, $log, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

And it hasn't logged a single hit. Even after our testers experienced the bug.

Is it possible that the receiving application is breaking the URL somehow?
What information should I be looking out for? Have you seen an issue like this before?

Is it the `http_build_query` that could be causing this and that my checker just doesn't work as expected (though, I did test it and it logged my test URL).

Any help on the matter would be great.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the infinite loop URL, please? Why did you choose to use http_build_query? do you have only param1 and param2 or more?

Comment: The infinite loop URL is pretty much the `www.target.com?param1=abc&param2=xyz&param1=abc&param2=xyz&param1=abc&param2=xyz&param1=abc&param2=xyz...` and so on. Sometimes I have more, other times I have less.

Comment: are you running under http or https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Assuming and issue with http_build_query:

Well, one attempt you may try is to rewrite the code without `$request->except` and `http_build_query`.
If you don't have any special reason to use `http_build_query` i would suggest to use `$request->input`.

**Example with $request->input:**

```
function out (Request $request) {
    $url = $request->target;

    $param1 = $request->input('param1', '');
    $param2 = $request->input('param2', '');

    if (!empty($param1) || !empty($param2)) {
        $url .= '?';
    }

    if (!empty($param1) && !empty($param2)) {
        $url .= 'param1=' . $param1 . '&param2=' . $param2;
    } else {
        $url .= !empty($param1) 'param1=' . $param1 : '';
        $url .= !empty($param2) 'param2=' . $param2 : '';
    }

    return redirect($url);
}
```

The solution is a little bit more verbose but with that, you should be sure 100% that is not the code to generate the redundancy.

## Absurd, remote possibility:

The second thing I would try is to check you log system. For instance if you are running under `apache` you should have a file called `access.log` under `/var/log/apache2/` (or under `/var/log/nginx/` with nginx).

In there you should have the history of all your http requests.

Maybe there is a chance that some of the wired requests with multiple params are from a strange IP address.
If this is the case, it means that some company is monitoring and testing the website (potentially with the strange parameters) for security reasons.
If this is the case, I guess you are under http and you should switch to https.

Anyway, with the new code, you should be sure about the code and be able to investigate any other part of the system.